# Does a DMA controller have its own registers?

Tags: memory-management, cpu-registers, dma

I'm trying to understand the ins and outs of how a DMA controller functions.

I'm looking at the 8237 DMA controller. Some information [here](http://zet.aluzina.org/index.php/8237_DMA_controller) has some tables with register values.

Are those the DMA's own registers, or are they the CPU's registers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DMA controller registers are distinct from the CPU registers (in the case of the 8237, it's physically a different chip with different silicon). When programming, you can access the DMA controller registers using CPU `IN` and `OUT` instructions as described on the page you linked (that's the "I/O Port" column).

A different hardware architecture may provide a different method of accessing a DMA controller registers, for example they could be "memory-mapped" instead of I/O ports.

Comment: And you should also note that the "IO Port" number is the number as far as the DMA controller is concerned. The number as far as the CPU is concerned will depend on how the chip is mapped into the CPU's I/O space. So if the chip is mapped at 400H, then chip register 87H will be CPU I/O port 487H.